# Probability sampling involving holidays

Tags: probability, sampling

Four people choose at random one holiday destination among ten
destinations. Show that the probability that at least two people will make the same choice is less than 1/2.

So far I have deduced that sampling is unordered and repetition is allowed, so to find the size of the sample space, I did (n+r-1)C(r), which gave me 715. Then to find the size of the event two people choose the same destination, I did 1/10*1/10, and then divided these two sizes to get 1/71500.

Is this the correct answer?

So 1/71500 is clearly less than 1/2

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this the wrong way. The probability that at least two people select the same destination is equal to 1 minus the probability that all four people choose a different destination. In the latter case, the first person can select 10 destinations, the second person 9 (as he or she cannot select the one chosen by the first person), the third person 8 and the fourth person 7. The probability that at least two people select the same destination thus equals:

$$1 - \frac{10}{10} \cdot \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{8}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{10} = 0.496 < 0.5$$

Comment: I understand your explanation, but I don't understand how you got those fractions? Actually I understand it now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

number of all possible holiday choices = $10^4$
number of holiday choices with multiple bookings not possible = 10x9x8x7 = 10!/ 6!

P(no multiple booking) = $(10! / 6!) / 10^4 = \frac{63}{125}$

there is therefore a $\frac{62}{125}$ chance that there will be a duplicate choice